# Deploy perf servlet in Websphere 7

Tags: websphere-7

I am new to WAS. I need to deploy perf servlet in my Websphere Application Server 7 environment for monitoring purposes. Is it ok to create a new Server in my existing node and deploy the servlet there? If yes, how do I target my deployment to a particular app server?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

thanks.

Comment: Are you using Deployment Manager and you have federated nodes, or you have just one, standalone server?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new node. You can run it on your existing node.